# @OneToOne with shared foreign key column

Tags: foreign-keys

I have these classes, and File is used in more entities depending on referenceType and referenceId. I want to set on Entrance the file association using reference_id column and reference_type = "ENTRANCE". Is it possible?

Tanks

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class File {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private Long referenceId;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FileReferenceType referenceType;
    private String fileName;
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    private LocalDateTime dateLastModified;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Entrance {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String business;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "reference_id", )
    private File file;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

is so easy as add an @Where(clause = "reference_type = 'ENTRANCE'") after @JoinColumn